# CSS layout head scratcher with min-width content and max-width margins

Tags: html, css, layout

I'd like a layout that looks like this:

```
----------------------containing div--------------------------
|              |                              |              |
| left margin  |         content area         | right margin |
| max-width=80 |        min-width=1024        | max-width=80 |
|              |                              |              |
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

So the desired behavior is

- `div width < 1024` -- margin areas shrink to 0 and content gets a horizontal scroll bar
- `1024 <= div width <= 1184` -- content area is 1024; margin areas expand up to 80 pixels.
- `1184 < div width` -- margin areas remain at 80 pixels and content area expands as much as it needs to fill the width of the div.

Can I implement this with HTML and CSS without JavaScript?  I have lots of flexibility about  how I arrange the HTML and CSS. So for example I don't mind if I need to use extra div's for the margin areas, several nested div's, or a combination of floats.  I'd prefer to avoid a wacky combination of media queries, but I'll take that if it's that's the best I can get.

If it can't be done, an acceptable answer would provide some insight about how to think about such a layout problem so that I don't have to waste so much time in the future :)

BTW -- It only needs to work for reasonably up-to-date Firefox and Webkit browsers -- IE isn't important for this application.

Comment: Yes.  You will want to use css media queries - they are a powerful way to change css depending on browser width.

Comment: I suggest taking a look at flexbox. [This](http://weblog.bocoup.com/dive-into-flexbox/) is a great introduction. And [this article](http://css-tricks.com/using-flexbox/) on CSS tricks shows how to mix old and new syntax.

Comment: If only flex box was properly supported.

Comment: What's wrong with `max-width: 10245px; margin: 0 auto;`?

Comment: @hungerstar -- the problem is that the margins need to be limited to 80 pixels wide -- the content area expands as needed, but is minimally 1024px.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) to achieve your goal. See a live demo [here](http://jsbin.com/avubod/1/edit).

#### HTML

```
<body>  
<div class="my-div">
    My Div
</div>
</body>
```

#### CSS

```
body, html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    background: #aaa;
}

.my-div {
    background: #ddd;
}

@media all and (max-width: 1023px) {
    .my-div {
        background: #aaaa99;
        margin: 0 0;
    }
}

@media all and (min-width: 1024px) and (max-width: 1183px) {
    .my-div {
        background: #aa99aa;
        width: 1024px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
}

@media all and (min-width: 1184px) {
    .my-div {
        background: #99aaaa;
        margin: 0 80px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks -- it seems media query is the way to go after all.

Answer (score 0):

This option attempts to mimic a table.

My jsFiddle uses smaller proportians than you need and are meant as an example case.  I also added a little jQuery to add content to the `#content` DIV when clicked on so you can see the max-width working.

http://jsfiddle.net/Kzw7d/2/

I added in a `min-height` and `background-color` for testing and clarity.

**CSS**

```css
#app-container {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
    display: table-row;
}
#content {
    min-height: 800px;
    min-width: 300px;
    max-width: 525px;
    background-color: red;
    word-wrap: break-all;
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;}
.margin {
    width: 80px;
    background-color: green;
    display: table-cell;
}
```

**HTML**

```html
<div id="app-container">
    <div class="margin"></div>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <div class="margin"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for a good try.  The problem with your fiddle is that the content has a fixed width=300px.  My content expands but keeps the margins fixed once they get to 80pixels.  Setting the max-width instead of width breaks the scroll bar requirement for lower width values.

Comment: Okay, missed the flexible content area part.